# Why does a function need a fixed number of arguments?

Tags: functions

I was thinking about how common commutative and associative operations can be thought of as acting on several numbers even though we do it in many separate binary steps, such as $a+b+c+d$ being expressible as $a+(b+(c+d))$ and we call the value that any of these expressions have as their 'Sum' but can we define a function/operation or mapping that takes $n$ number inputs for any $n$ and returns their sum? The issue is, we could give it $3$ inputs, or two inputs and for each there would be a different tuple, (or real number), so the function would have a non-constant number of arguments, is this possible to define?

As in general for a function $f(x_1,x_2....x_n$) for a different $n$ it must be a different function denoted by $f$.

Comment: Perhaps more a consequence of history than objective mathematical necessity, [variadic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) are primarily a matter of computer science rather than standard mathematical practice. But if I define functions $f_n$ of domain $A^n$ and codomain $B$ and take these functions' union, I get a function of domain $\bigcup_nA^n$, which is often but by no means always an inconvenient concept.

Comment: What is it you mean by an union of functions, exactly? For instance, if $x \in A^n \subset A^m$, and $f_n(x) \neq f_m(x)$, how is the union defined at $x$?

Comment: @J.G. So they exist, but it's not particularly common practice to do so?

Comment: If you're into databases, the SQL programming language has the concept of aggregate/aggregating functions that behave rather like what you describe.

Comment: @DouglasFinamore If we identify a function $f$ with the set of ordered pairs of the form $(x,\,f(x))$, and functions have no common domain values (except maybe ones on which they're equal), the union of these sets is also identifiable with a function.

Comment: @DouglasFinamore In what sense can we say $A^n \subset A^m$ where $n \neq m$? Doesn't it usually come along with a requirement that we only allow functions whose values are "the same" on points that are "the same"? It seems to me that's what you do in your answer for $\mathbb R^m$ and $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$. (By the way, there's no such restriction on variadic functions in typical computer languages.)

Comment: @DavidK Oh sure, you're talking about Cartesian products. For some reason I as thinking of $A^n$ as sequence of arbitray sets and not as a nested sequence of products. It makes total sense, my bad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strictly speaking a function can be regarded as a quadruple of

- A label or name, like $\sin$.
- A domain $D$.
- A codomain $C$.
- A mapping that for each element of $D$ tells how to "compute" its image in $C$.

Functions with variable number of arguments can be convenient, there are several ways to approach them.

### I. Use different functions with the same label

(Ab)using notation, you could have functions with the same name indexed by their number of arguments like:

$$\gcd\nolimits_n:\Bbb Z^n\to\Bbb Z$$
defined recursively as

$$\gcd\nolimits_n(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\begin{cases}
x_1, &\text{ if } n=1\\
\gcd(x_1, x_2), &\text{ if } n=2\\
\gcd(\gcd_\nolimits{n-1}(x_1,\dots, x_{n-1}), x_n), &\text{ if } n>2\\
\end{cases}$$
and then, as a matter of convenience / lazyness, drop the index and just write $\gcd(a,b,c,d)$ etc. where it's unabgiguously clear that you mean the specimen $\gcd_4$.

### II. Use a domain that contains all possible $n$-tuples

You can use a domain that contais all possible tuples of values:
$$D^\cup=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N} D = D\cup D^2\cup D^3\cup\cdots$$

The $\gcd$-example from above would be $\gcd:\Bbb Z^\cup\to\Bbb Z$.   Notice however, that we didn't yet define the function law, and doing it recursively gets much more convoluted than with approach I.  To write it down, we'd need to define a function that "forgets" the last component of a $n$-dimensional vector etc., and all that notations is just cluttering up things and making things more convoluted than needed.

### III. Use already existing notation

As you are referrung to sums:
Functions with variable number of arguments are already in wide-spread use, and using them is usually not a deep dive in the rabbithole of nitpicking, it's just a notation that's been taken for granted.  For example, the sum notation $\sum$ is a very generic device.  It's supposed to be meaningful over any domain that knows of summation, different notations of specifying the indices are understood, etc. like

$$\sum_{n\in\Bbb N}\frac1{n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}$$

and it can even cope with zero arguments: The empty sum is defined to be $0$.

### On Notation

The previous sections make it very clear that variable-argument functions is more a matter of notation, that help to improve reader's experience by *not* going into 200% nitpick mode.  To that end, the notation for arguments that are vectors is already bit sloppy but still consistent.  Take for example again $$\gcd:\Bbb Z^2\to\Bbb Z$$
This can be seen as

- A function that takes two arguments from $\Bbb Z$.
- A function that takes one vector-argument from $\Bbb Z^2$.

In the first case, the notation is $\gcd(a,b)$ with $a,b\in\Bbb Z$. In the second case, it is $\gcd(v)=\gcd((a,b))$ with $v=(a,b)\in\Bbb Z^2$.

Comment: For [gcd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor), in particular, the natural generalization is in fact to define it as a function from $\mathcal P(\mathbb Z)$ (i.e. the set of sets of integers) to $\mathbb N$, with $\gcd(\emptyset)=\gcd(\{0\})=0$ and $\gcd(S)$ for all other $S\subseteq\mathbb Z$ is the largest $n\in\mathbb N$ such that every number $x\in S$ can be written as $x = nk$ for some integer $k$. Showing that $\gcd(S)$ is indeed well defined for all $S\subseteq\mathbb Z$ and that $\gcd(\{a,b,c,…\})=\gcd(a,\gcd(b,\gcd(c,…)))$ for finite sets is left as an exercise. :)

Answer (score 2):

The way functions are defined is as a relation between two sets. A function $f: A \to B$ can be thought as a subset $G = (x, f(x))$ of the cartesian product
$$A \times B = \{ (a,b); a \in A, b \in B\}$$
satisfying the property that for each $x \in A$ there's is **only one** $f(x) \in B$ such that $(x, f(x)) \in G$. Heuristically, this is basically defining what a function is by means of its graph. Of course, what we usually do in a daily basis is to think of $f$ not as an subset, but as a rule $x \mapsto f(x)$ relating to each object of $A$ an object in $B$

In this sense, you could say that, technically, every function $f$ has *only one argument*, which is the element in $A$. When you write something like $f(x_1, \cdots, x_n)$ and say $f$ is a function of $n$ arguments you are simply considering a function whose domain $A$ is written as product $A = A_1 \times A_2 \times \cdots \times A_n$. In this case, each $n$-tuple $(x_1, \cdots, x_n)$ is a single element $x$ of $A$, so in the end $f(x_1, \cdots, x_n)$ is simply $f(x)$.

By adding or removing arguments I'm changing the product $A$, so I end up with different functions, strictly speaking, because I'm varying the domain.

What you can do is consider a huge set with all possible arguments, and fill most of them with constants. Let's think of real numbers, for example. You let the domain be
$$ \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N} = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \cdots = \{(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n, \cdots); x_i \in \mathbb{R}\}, $$
which is basically the set of all sequences $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. Let $f:\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N} \to B$ be a function. If you make the convention that every $m$-tuple $(x_1, \cdots, x_m)$ corresponds to the sequence $(x_1, \cdots, x_m, 0, 0, 0, \cdots)$, then it makes sense to write things like $f(x_1, x_2)$ or $f(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4,x_5)$, and you can think of this as a fucntion where the number of arguments is varying. But in the end there is only one argument, which is a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$.

This would work in a general infinite product $A_1 \times A_2 \times \cdots$ as well, but then you would have to choose elements $a_n \in A_n$ to play the role of $0$.

---

Comment: This works OK for $a + b + c + d,$ not so well (I think) for $a \cdot b \cdot c \cdot d.$

Comment: For multiplication of an arbitray number of elements to make sense you would have to "fill" the sequences with $1$'s. But in any case, my intention was to show a way in which a function _already defined_ in a large countable cartesian product can be seem as function of a any finite number of elements. As for the answer to OP actual question, "why do we need a fixed number of arguments", I believe it would be that, formally, functions have actually only one argument.

Comment: Right, the main point is *one argument*. You make that quite clear in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually simulate a function with an arbitrary finite number of arguments: if the domain of your variables is $X$, then your function's domain could be $\coprod_{n\in \mathbb N}X^n$.